# Charge 18650 3S pack through USB C

Tags: batteries

I have 3x 18650s wired in a series, connected to the BMS seen [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077ZY7Z3G). The two outputs of the BMS are wired to a MOSFET that drops the voltage from 12 to 5, in order to power an Arduino Trinket Pro.

During prototyping I was using your basic DC jack to connect to the Arduino and charge the battery pack. However with the 3D printed part I have this all in I am using a different battery contact to connect the battery pack and Arduino.

Now I am needing to find a different way to charge the battery pack, preferably through a micro USB or USB C charging port, like you see on portable power packs.

I've picked up the TP4056, [seen here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LZSC7I8), and the USB C version. My question is can I / would it be a good idea to splice off of the BMS outputs, and insert a diode into the connection between the battery contact that connects to the Arduino and a diode into where the TP4056 runs.

The first time I had tried it with a standard micro USB port, no diodes, which heated up very quickly.

Or, would I be better off just running the TP4056 straight to the positive and negative terminals on the pack itself, bypassing the USB. [image]

Comment: [MOSFET drops the voltage from 12 to 5, in order to power an Arduino] = very lossy. Have you considered a [switcher](https://www.mouser.com/Power/DC-DC-Converters/_/N-brvxeZ1yzvvqx?P=1yx5k7vZ1y8fpf1Z1yxt7eu)?

Comment: No I have not - I will have to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Three 18650 lithium battery cells will be 12.6V when fully charged. The TP4056 is made to charge one cell or a few paralleled cells to 4.2V so it will not charge your cells that are in series. A Mosfet by itself will not regulate the 12.6V down to 5V.

Comment: The Mosfet is the L7805CV, while not the most efficient, it works for this prototype. Any ideas on what to use instead of the TP4056, potentially wire 3 TP4056s together to a single micro usb port?

Comment: The L7805 is a linear voltage regulator IC, not a MOSFET.

Comment: If you are reducing 12 volts from the battery to 5 volts using a 7805, you are wasting 60% of the battery power heating up the7805.